# When I type "rails server", I get an error "Could not find gem 'turn <>=0>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am totally new to ror. Installed it today. Created the first app following Lynda instructions. Within the app folder, tried to run WEBrick but got this mistake:

> Could not find gem 'turn<>=0>' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gem.

I did run "bundle install", but it didn't help. I get the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason not everything is installed by budler. Some gems must be installed as root.

Try: `sudo gem install turn`

Comment: One possible issue might be, that You are missing some other gem's dependencies. I has some issues with sqlite3 and therefore bundler did not install gems either. If You seem to have a similar problem, installl sqlite3-dev package first and then bundler should also work nicely.